# JS reading MySQL rows into multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, mysql, multidimensional-array

In my JS script I have:

```
var originalArray = [
  ['t00', ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Carrot', 'Yike'], [25, 317, 2]],
  ['t01', ['Mozart', 'Beethoven'], [2, 30, 9, 77, 1, 20]]
];
```

There's a piece of code, which runs ONCE in its life, and writes all items of the array to MySQL table :

[image]

The two **array** fields "**tstArr1**" and "**tstArr2**" are defined as **TEXT** fields.
I can change this so it will write to the DB these 2 arrays at any format.

Now I read this table and need to rebuild the `originalArray` in a new empty array called `newArray`:

```
var newArray = [];
```

But I can't get it to be exactly the same as the `originalArray`.

Here is how I read and (unsuccessfully) populate `newArray` :

```
    function readEvent() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'DB_read.php', true);
        xhr.onload = function () {
            if (this.status == 200) {
                var DB_response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                for (let i in DB_response) {
                    let tstArr1_from_db = DB_response[i].tstArr1;
                    let tstArr2_from_db = DB_response[i].tstArr2;
                    newArray.push(DB_response[i].tstName, tstArr1_from_db, tstArr2_from_db);
                }
            }
            console.table(originalArray);               //
            console.log(originalArray[1][1][1]);        //      f o r 
            console.table(newArray);                    //  d e b u g g i n g
            console.log(newArray[1][1][1]);             //
        }
        xhr.send();
    }
```

The console shows :
[image]

The "undefined" is obvious.

How can I make `newArray` a multidimension array like the original one?

Thank you, clever people.

(Please, please....  no jquery)

Comment: What exactly is the data in `DB_respone`?

Comment: @VLAS - The data in `DB_response` is exactly as @Abelucho assumed in his answer, which was perfect for me.  Thanks anyhow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asume that your response is text, so the data is `'Apple, Banana, Carrot, Yike'` and `'25, 317, 2'` for the first row, then you need to split the string into an array.

```js
var originalArray = [
  ['t00', ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Carrot', 'Yike'], [25, 317, 2]],
  ['t01', ['Mozart', 'Beethoven'], [2, 30, 9, 77, 1, 20]]
];

//assumed your response have this structure
var DB_response = [
  {tstName:'t00', tstArr1:'Apple, Banana, Carrot, Yike', tstArr2:'25, 317, 2'},
  {tstName:'t01', tstArr1:'Mozart,Beethoven', tstArr2:'2, 30, 9, 77, 1, 20'}
];

function test() {
  var newArray = [];
  DB_response.forEach(function(db) {
    field1 = db.tstName;
    field2 = db.tstArr1.split(',').map(function(s) {return s.trim()})
    field3 = db.tstArr2.split(',').map(function(s) {return s.trim()})
    newArray.push([field1,field2,field3]);
  })
  console.log(originalArray,newArray);
}
```

```html
<button onclick='test()'>Test</buton>
```

Comment: Oh man! Thank you so much. I spent 2 night on it. I'm going to sleep now. Thank you big time again and good night...!